# DBeaver error returned connecting to Db2 database using SSL/TLS with hostname validation error

Tags: db2, connectivity, db2-luw, dbeaver, tls-1.2

I have configured SSL/TLS on Db2/Linux v11.5.7.0. In DBeaver 22.1.5 (Java GUI program to access database) in *Driver properties* I have configured parameter:
`sslConnection` to `true` and DBeaver successfully connects to Db2 user using SSL/TLS.

[According to Db2 Java Driver documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=pdsdjs-common-data-server-driver-jdbc-sqlj-properties-all-database-products) in DBeaver at *Driver properties* I have configured `sslClientHostnameValidation` to `BASIC` to enable Db2 client to execute hostname validation.

When I double click to establish connection in DBeaver I get error:

> [jcc][t4][20162][14259][4.31.10] Connection failed: could not
> establish a SSL connection with the server. The connection has been
> configured to use hostname validation and the servers TLS certificate
> does not contain a hostname or IP address which matches the value
> configured by the client. ERRORCODE=-20576, SQLSTATE=08001

To troubleshoot the problem, in DBeaver I enabled *Connection calls* trace and the output is:

> [jcc][Time:2022-09-01-13:32:11.588][Thread:Connect to
> 'test1ssl_hostname_validation'][Connection@1fcbbce6]doHostnameValidation
> () called [jcc][Time:2022-09-01-13:32:11.588][Thread:Connect to
> 'test1ssl_hostname_validation'][Connection@1fcbbce6]doHostnameValidation
> () returned sslIsHostnameValid=false

It does not tell anything about what was the hostname it checked.

I have read Db2 documentation [Troubleshooting hostname validation at the client when negotiating a TLS connection](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=validation-troubleshooting-hostname) and according to documentation error should be logged into db2diag.log at Db2 server site. But there is no error at all recorded in my case.

I have even increased DIAGLEVEL dbm cfg parameter to maximum 4 and restarted the instance, reproduced the problem, but still no error is displayed in db2diag.log

For certificate I have double check Subject Alternative Name and there is correctly set FQDN.

How can I verify which hostname did client recognized and which hostname did it get from certificate?
Regards

Comment: Try both forward and reverse name resolution from the client: they should both yield the same hostname, and that hostname must be present in the server certificate.

Answer (score 1):

From *CONNECT* trace I have found out that `serverName` was set to `localhost` instead of server name.

1. Right click on connection and select **Edit Connection**.
2. Make sure **Connection setting** | **Main** tab | **Database** section | **Host** field has the same value as SSL certificate's:

- *Subject Alternative Name* and/or
- *Subject/CN* value

Because my Db2 server is running inside VirtualBox machine accessed using Port Forwarding I solved the problem:

1. In DBeaver at **Connection Settings** | **Main** tab | **Host** field I have set my server name FQDM.
2. In C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file I have added new line starting with set: `127.0.0.1` then space and my server's FQDM.
3. In DBeaver connect and connect is successful.